# How to provide a session to a NextAuth Session provider?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I have the problem that my SessionProvider wants to get a session, but I don't know where to fetch it from.

```
// Layout.tsx

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="de">
      <Provider>
        <body className={inter.className}>
          <AppRouterCacheProvider options={{ key: "css" }}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
          </AppRouterCacheProvider>
        </body>
      </Provider>
    </html>
  );
}
```

```
// Provider.tsx
"use client";
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import { Session } from "next-auth";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

interface ProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  session: Session | null;
}

export default function Provider({ children, session }: ProviderProps) {
  return <SessionProvider session={session}>{children}</SessionProvider>;
}
```

```
// [...nextauth].tsx
 import NextAuth, { getServerSession, type NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import connectToDatabase from "@/util/db";
import User from "@/models/User";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
      }
      return token;
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      if (session.user && token.id) {
        session.user.id = token.id;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/singin",
  },
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {},
        password: {},
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        if (!credentials) {
          return null;
        }

        await connectToDatabase();

        const user = await User.findOne({ username: credentials.email });

        if (
          !user ||
          !(await bcrypt.compare(credentials.password, user.password))
        ) {
          return null;
        }

        return { id: user.id, name: user.username, email: user.email };
      },
    }),
  ],
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

export const getServerAuthSession = () => getServerSession(authOptions);
```

I'll get the following error, when using it that way:

```
Property 'session' is missing in type '{ children: Element; }' but required in type 'ProviderProps'.ts(2741)
Provider.tsx(8, 3): 'session' is declared here.
(alias) function Provider({ children, session }: ProviderProps): JSX.Element
import Provider
```

I tried multiple Methods like get the session data via getStaticProps etc. and tried different tutorials and guides online but no one seems to have the same problem.